# How should I use "infer"?

Tags: meaning

A recent [question on Meta](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54/should-we-use-simple-words-when-possible) discussed advantages and disadvantages of using more advanced words in ELL. As example, [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/185/54) was used:

> 'A Japanese' **infers** the Japanese person is a thing, and not a person.
>   This is what **deems** it offensive.
>
> 'A Japanese Person' **infers** the Japanese person is just that - a
>   person, and is therefore considered fine for use.

While the conclusion of the discussion is not related to this question, one comment disturbed me:

> Unhappily, both words are misused there! – StoneyB 18 hours ago

Not to bundle two unrelated words and two different errors, let's focus on **infers** here. What is the misuse in the example? How should that word be used here correctly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To *infer* is to understand or realize a fact that is not immediately obvious. To *imply* is to "say something without saying it", so to speak; when you imply something, you are indicating it to be true without ever actually saying it outright. You infer what I imply; I infer what you imply.

So, to put it in context, the phrase "A Japanese" may *imply* something offensive, but *you*, as a listener or reader, have *inferred* this.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I'm aware the error here is that 'infer' actually applies to how someone responds to something that is said/written, rather than the effect of the thing itself.

That is to say, someone infers something when they 'read between the lines' or spots something that isn't stated outright - they don't 'infer' when they say something, so the current usage is incorrect.

This said, the example could be rewritten correctly like this (even if it is a bit clunky):

> 'A Japanese' could lead someone to **infer** that the Japanese person is a thing, and not a person.
>   This is what deems it offensive.
>
> 'A Japanese Person' would lead someone to **infer** that the Japanese person is just that - a
>   person, and is therefore considered fine for use.

(NB: as the question doesn't refer to 'deems', I've left it uncorrected)

However, in this case, I think the author was actually looking for the word '*implies*', which means that something is said (even if unintentionally), but not outright stated. To use the example again:

> 'A Japanese' **implies** that the Japanese person is a thing, and not a person.
>   This is what deems it offensive.
>
> 'A Japanese Person' **implies** that the Japanese person is just that - a
>   person, and is therefore considered fine for use.

Answer (score 4):

To **infer** is to extract from a proposition or text or signal, by what we call  **inference**, a sense which is not literally there, which is not explicit.

Thus, I **inferred** from the fact that the subjects of OP's sentences were texts, not persons, that the word OP intended was not *infer* but **imply**, which means to carry or bear a sense which is not literally there—which is not explicit but **implicit**.

Answer (score 0):

The NOAD reports the following notes, about *imply* and *refer*:

> There is a distinction in meaning between *infer* and *imply*. In the sentence "the speaker implied that the general had been a traitor," the word *implied* means that something in the speaker's words *suggested* that this man was a traitor (although nothing so explicit was actually stated). However, in "we inferred from his words that the general had been a traitor," the word *inferred* means that something in the speaker's words enabled the listeners to *deduce* that the man was a traitor. The two words *infer* and *imply* can describe the same event, but from different angles. Mistakes occur when *infer* is used to mean *imply*, as in "Are you inferring that I'm a liar?" (instead of "Are you implying that I'm a liar?").

Comment: What is NOAD?..