# How should I use "deem"?

Tags: meaning

In relation to [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/850/correct-usage-of-infer) about using "Infer" I'd like to ask what is wrong with **deem** in this example? How to use it correctly?

> 'A Japanese' **infers** the Japanese person is a thing, and not a person.
>   This is what **deems** it offensive.
>
> 'A Japanese Person' **infers** the Japanese person is just that - a
>   person, and is therefore considered fine for use.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"To deem" is an action of consciously deciding. It is an action taken by a sentient being. So to say that some factual evidence "deems" something is nonsensical, as facts are merely ideas, not people or beings with the capacity to make decisions.

It would perhaps be more appropriate to rephrase:

> 'A Japanese' implies the Japanese person is a thing, and not a person. This is what caused certain people to deem it offensive.

(Note that I also changed *infers* to *implies. This is the subject of another question, but please research it if you don't know why I did that.)

EDIT: Ah, I just saw the reference to [the other question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/850/correct-usage-of-infer), re: *infer*. And then I answered the other question. So... go check that out.

Answer (score 3):

Let us  ignore the *infer* / *imply* confusion, which is covered by [another question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/850/).

*Deem* means *consider*, and in the example *deems it offensive* is backwards. 
*Someone* must deem *something* offensive.  An inanimate object can't deem; it can only *be deemed*.

I find *deem* to be rather old-fashioned, and would use *consider* instead.

(Bias: US native, of an "older" generation.)

Comment: I find that deem is still used pretty frequently in certain contexts. (Also a US native, though of a younger generation. )

Comment: UK, older generation. But ***not so old*** that I would use *deem* myself in conversation (except facetiously). The word was [well into decline](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+deem+it&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) before Queen Victoria gave up the ghost.

Answer (score 0):

"deem" is one of the more overused words in undergraduate writing.  It isn't simply a synonym for "thinks" and its use is quite restricted to specific environments. A better synonym is "consider", and you can sometimes swap the two.  "deem", however, is more formal and a bit old fashioned. Usually, "deem" is intransitive, so it doesn't take a direct object. You can say "I will take whatever action I deem appropriate", but "I deem that action appropriate" is non-idiomatic.

Comment: "deem" has many meanings, not just one. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deem