# Is "Alien" a term normally used for foreigners?

Tags: word-usage, american-english

When used in the context of foreigners, rather than extra-terrestrial beings, is "Alien" commonly used?

I suspect that it's only used in [legal contexts](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/6102/1420), such as government forms. But I'm not totally familiar with American English, so I don't know if it's more common in the USA. Is it used outside of legal contexts there? For example, could you say "Aliens are surprised when I tell them I don't have a television"?

Comment: You got it mostly right; *alien* is a legal term. But it's also popular with those who despise foreigners or resent their presence.

Comment: @StoneyB is this with regards to Mexicans living in America (who are sometimes referred to as "illegal aliens"), or others as well?

Comment: That's the hot-button issue right now, of course. But people who don't like perfectly legal immigrants from somewhere like, say Papua-New Guinea, will refer to them as "aliens in our midst".

Comment: I wouldn't understand the sentence in your question without further context. As you mentioned in your comment, "illegal aliens" is the complete term to refer to illegal immigrants, and if you used the term in its entirety you would be understood. But "alien" simply by itself would refer to extra-terrestrials, yes.

Comment: I would think "foreigners" would be much more common than "aliens". Your "aliens are surprised" sentence sounds very alien to me.

Comment: Andrew Grimm, in that context, it seems that the word is just a part of American English.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, I'll put on a veneer of scientific-ness and consult a corpus!

I searched the [*Corpus of Contemporary American English* (COCA)](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) for ***alien***.  That had 8783 results, which is a lot more than I intended to look at, so I clicked the `SAMPLE: 100` link to get a random sample of 100 results.  (The order of the first 100 results is *not* random by default, so that's a helpful thing to do.)

Looking at those results, here's what I noticed:

- *Alien* by itself usually means *space alien*.
- *Alien* is used sometimes in legal contexts, usually in terms like *legal resident alien* or *illegal alien*, though it does occasionally appear by itself.
- When people are described as *"aliens"*, it's often put in quotes as though it's an unusual term.

Although these results are based on a corpus of published material, these observations fit my intuition about how the term is used in American English.  Personally, as a speaker of American English, if I heard your sentence:

> ***Aliens*** are surprised when I tell them I don't have a television.

I'd assume you meant *space aliens*, and this assumption is supported by the corpus results I looked through.

---

And now for my *opinion*:

My personal impression is that the term *alien* is very "other-izing".  It's a term that makes whatever you're describing feel **very** different and unfamiliar.  My feeling is that it's not appropriate to apply to people outside of specialized contexts precisely because people aren't "other" enough.  We're all humans, after all!

If my impression is correct, it might follow that xenophobes (people who fear the "other") are more likely to use this term to describe people.  And for both of these reasons, I think it's possible that people could feel marginalized by the term or take offense to it.  So to me, it feels like it's best to avoid using *alien* this way.

My guess is that this is true outside the U.S. as well, but I don't really know.

Comment: I wonder if there's a connection between a word being unusual and it being offensive? Some view "A Japanese" as unusual, and some view it as offensive: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/183/54

Comment: @AndrewGrimm This is just my opinion again, but I think that's very plausible.  If you call someone something they aren't used to being called, I suppose they might notice and wonder *why* you called them that...

Comment: +1. As an aside, I believe most xenophobes wouldn't use the word _alien_, but only because _alien_ has come to mean "extraterrestial alien." A more familiar term would be _foreigners_, and xenophobes would be more likely use something like _damned foreigners_, as opposed to carefully selecting a different word like "aliens" to convey their feelings on the subject more subtly.

Comment: FWIW I've lived in Germany for a while and have a few papers referring to me as "alien". As a result that got me thinking how exclusive the term is even for a country as socially concerned as Germany.